# How to make the Arrow (EMPTY) appear?

Tags: modeling, mesh, object-mode

I am making a project that would require me to use an empty which is an arrow however when I add one  I can't see any arrow on the screen on ta yellow dot.
[image: t]

Comment: yes that's weird, maybe share a file with just an empty: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Empties are plain axis by default. You have to change it to be arrow, and can change the size if you need to. Is that the problem?

Comment: As well as size=0 in display options, check you haven't unchecked "Extra" in the viewport overlay... https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#objects